# Api Token auth how to avoid man-in-the-middle

Tags: api, security, rest, ssl, access-token

Let's imagine that I don't use SSL and I send a token in a HTTP headers. The token contains the user ID and is encrypted.

I can imagine that a man-in-the-middle attacker could capture the token and use it. If I use SSL it should be secure enough? But if I don't use SSL...

Can I add something to the token like for example the user's IP so I can check that the request IP and the encrypted IP in the token are the same?

Can the man-in-the-middle attacker fake the IP address of the victim? Can I use any other user related information when generating the token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can the man-in-the-middle attacker (MITM) fake the IP address of the victim?

Since you describe the possible attack a "man-in-the-middle," yes the attacker can fake the IP address of the victim.

> Can I use any other user related information when generating the token?

Sure, have the user generate a random number that never gets sent in the clear. And better make sure the server also does the same, so that a man-in-the-middle attacker can't just replay an old request. And how can the user be sure that he's communicating with the real server and not the attacker? Better prove the server's identity with a certificate.

There are many such questions that come up in designing a protocol that's secure against man-in-the-middle attacks. If you address all of them, you'll probably come up with something very similar to SSL. For many developers, it's just not worth their time to build their own secure transport protocol.

Comment: "generate a random number that never gets sent in the clear" - How could you accomplish that without SSL? If you send the user an encryption key the key itself can be also sniffed without SSL?

Answer (score 2):

Further to @guest's excellent answer:

> Can the man-in-the-middle attacker fake the IP address of the victim?

It depends where the MITM is:

- If they are at another computer on the same network as the victim (but not the server) then they may share the same public IP anyway. The MITM is intercepting the victim's traffic but will not need to spoof the IP address as your system will only see the public IP which will be the same.
- If they are within your server infrastructure network then may be able to use something like [ARP Poisoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) to intercept traffic - no spoofing of the victim's IP is necessary here.
- If they are somewhere in between (e.g. a government controlled backbone connection) then spoofing the IP may be more difficult if not impossible (spoofing an IP means that the attacker won't be able to read any replies to their packets as they will be sent back to the spoofed IP).

In short, use SSL (or more technically TLS).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If somebody can use another computer on the same network that is not something that I can really control (I'm just developing a web framework) it would be up to the users to secure their own private network. The hosting network should be secure enough (An IaaS provider like Amazon or Microsoft). The case that makes me worry is the "somewhere in between". I want to make sure that if somebody doesn't use TLS my framework will still be as secure as possible based on your answer I think I will use the IP as part of the token and recommend to use TLS to the framework users